# SQL Server group by with date differences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this line of codes

```
select min(A.id) 'id',
      CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),min(A.date_in),101) as 'Date_in',
      CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),min(A.date_in),108) as 'Time_in',
      CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),min(A.date_out),101) as 'Date_out',
      CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),min(A.date_out),108) as 'Time_out',
      min(B.firstname) 'firstname',min(B.lastname) 'lastname', 
      min(A.ip_address) 'ip_address',
      CASE min(B.UserType)
        WHEN 1029 THEN 'Administator'
        WHEN 1030 THEN 'Casheiring'
        WHEN 1031 THEN 'Front Office'
        WHEN 1032 THEN 'Housekeeping'
        WHEN 1033 THEN 'POS'
END as 'user_type'
from AEmployeeLogs A 
LEFT JOIN AUsers B on B.id = A.[user_id]
group by A.[user_id]
ORDER BY min(A.id) DESC
```

In this query i get this:

```
 id   Date_in     Time_In   Date Out     Time_Out   firstname  lastname  ip_address      user_type
 5    10/05/2017  15:14:59  10/05/2017   20:20:37   LeBron     James     192.168.0.1     Administrator
 1    10/04/2017  12:04:32  10/05/2017   16:02:53   Kevin      Durant    192.168.0.2     Administrator
```

These will get me the 2 ids that i grouped by I want that in every date should be there every time I wanted it to be like this:

```
  id   Date_in     Time_In   Date Out     Time_Out   firstname  lastname  ip_address      user_type
  5    10/05/2017  15:14:59  10/05/2017   20:20:37   LeBron     James     192.168.0.1     Administrator
  3    10/05/2017  11:58:20  10/05/2017   16:02:53   Kevin      Durant    192.168.0.2     Administrator
  1    10/04/2017  12:04:32  10/05/2017   16:02:53   Kevin      Durant    192.168.0.2     Administrator
```

It should have this output I just wanted to get min() in every date not the min() of the whole table even with the group by clause please help me and thank you :)

Comment: Well your query is getting min(A.id) but you are stating that you don't want that. Perhaps you don't want any grouping at all here? If you need more help you need to provide more details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Well i still want the id because i only wanted to get the first entry of that specific user in that day but my query getting the first entry of this specific user in the entire table lol

Comment: That is because that is what you told it to do. Sounds like you are taking the wrong approach to this.

Comment: And im asking for the correct approach to this so please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

```
select *
from
(
    select A.id,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), A.date_in,101) as 'Date_in',
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), A.date_in,108) as 'Time_in',
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), A.date_out,101) as 'Date_out',
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), A.date_out,108) as 'Time_out',
        B.firstname,
        B.lastname,
        A.ip_address,
        CASE B.UserType
            WHEN 1029 THEN 'Administator'
            WHEN 1030 THEN 'Casheiring'
            WHEN 1031 THEN 'Front Office'
            WHEN 1032 THEN 'Housekeeping'
            WHEN 1033 THEN 'POS'
        END as 'user_type'
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by A.id, A.date_in order by A.date_in)
    from AEmployeeLogs A 
    LEFT JOIN AUsers B on B.id = A.[user_id]
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
ORDER BY x.id DESC
```

Also, you should use better aliases than `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. That is a bad habit to get into.

- [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: this isnt working sir, it rather displays all the record

Comment: I am guessing as to what you want. Please post table definitions, sample data and desired output. But I think perhaps I just needed to add the date_in to the partition.

Comment: hey sir i just wanted you to know that the A.date_in is a datetime that is why i use CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), A.date_in,101) to get the date and CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), A.date_in,108) to get the time im sorry

Comment: @GGw changing `RowNum` to `ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by A.[user_id], cast(date_in as date) order by A.date_in)` should give you your desired result